# Django redirect within my code without changing display url and send right status code

Tags: django, subdomain, django-middleware

I'll like to redirect the url like my admin using subdomain without changing the url

```
 admin.example.com
```

so in my  middleware ill change this to

```
example.com/admin
```

but still display the url as if there was no redirect.

here is what my middleware currently looks like

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
sitename = getattr(settings,'SITE_DEFAULT_DOMAIN')[:4]


class SubdomainMiddleware(object):       
    def process_request(self, request):
        host = request.get_host()
        domain_parts = host.split('.')
        entry_url = "{0}://{1}{2}".format(request.META['wsgi.url_scheme'],\
                                          host,\
                                          request.get_full_path() )
        setattr(request,'entry_url',entry_url)
        if (len(domain_parts) > 2):
            subdomain = domain_parts[0]
            if subdomain.lower() not in ('www',sitename):
                request.incoming_path = request.META['PATH_INFO']
                domain = '.'.join(domain_parts[1:])
                if request.META['PATH_INFO'] == '/' :
                    path = "{0}{1}{2}".format('/',subdomain,'/')            
                else:
                    path = "{0}{1}{2}".format('/',subdomain,request.META['PATH_INFO'])
            else:
                domain = host.replace('www','')
                path = request.META['PATH_INFO']
            redirect_path = "{0}://{1}{2}".format(request.META['wsgi.url_scheme'],domain, path)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_path)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        entry_url = getattr(request,'entry_url',None)
        if entry_url:
            response.location = entry_url
        return response
```

Comment: Why? What's the point of changing the domain if you don't want to show it to the user?

Comment: The points is i want the subdomin to remain persistent so that every url to admin is served from that subdomin admin.example and not /admin  with out me needing to change any as my code is or any 3rpart app but just manupulate the url back an forth in my middleware

Comment: But why don't you just serve the admin site on its own from the admin.example.com subdomain, and leave it like that?

Comment: i have posted my code above

Comment: And you can't just use nginx or whatever webserver you are using to redirect for you?